# how to make a route accept # to access various paragraphs in a long page

Tags: laravel, routes

I am converting a site under symfony to laravel.
In symfony I use urls such as http://domain.ext/part1/part2#aparagraph
to access a specific paragraph in a very long page
Such urls are not accepted in laravel, probably because I don't know how to write the route

The page is accessible via

```
Route::get('/part1/part2', 'ACertainController@index')->name('aname');
```

My question is how to modify my route in order it accepts **any** #aparagraph ?

Comment: Your route looks good. The anchor support has nothing to do with laravel. It is just html functionality. This should be contained in the blade template that is returned by your controller function https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-anchor-link.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't still understand. The link you give seems to explain how to form a url with an anchor inside. it is not my trouble as the address of the link is correctly formed but leads only to the top of the page. For exemple if I enter http://part1/part2#ananchor directly in the address bar it leads to http://part1/part2 (top of page) but not to the ananchor anchor.

Comment: Do you have an element with an id of `ananchor` on your page?

Comment: Forget about this. My page sources are different in Laravel and Symfony. Probably because they are written in Markdown and markdown behave differently (I use parsedown and parsedown-extra in laravel and markdown in symfony).